# Blender Physics constraint implementation sources

Tags: physics, source-code

I wanted to know where exactly in sources, Blender implements the Bullet Physics for its rigid body constraint solving. That is, where does it pass the arguments such as Rigid Bodies, their orientation, mass, so on in order to set-up the constraint.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following files contain the implementation of the rigid bodies:

- [`properties_physics_rigidbody.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_physics_rigidbody.py): UI panels in the physics tab for the *Rigid Body*
- [`properties_physics_rigidbody_constraint.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_physics_rigidbody_constraint.py): UI panels in the physics tab for the *Rigid Body Constraint*
- [`rna_rigidbody.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_rigidbody.c): RNA properties for the rigid bodies.
- [`rigidbody.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/rigidbody.c): Initialization, copying, validating and freeing data structures for rigid body simulation. Functions for calculating volumes, mass, convex hull. Running and managing the simulation.
- [`rigidbody_world.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/physics/rigidbody_world.c): Implements operators that can be called from Python that are related to the rigid body world.
- [`rigidbody_constraint.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/physics/rigidbody_constraint.c): Implements operators that can be called from Python that are related to the rigid body constraint.
- [`rigidbody_object.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/physics/rigidbody_object.c): Implements operators that can be called from Python that are related to the rigid body object.
- [`rb_bullet_api.cpp`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/rigidbody/rb_bullet_api.cpp): Wrapper for Bullet Physics functions.

For the parts of code that use the Bullet Physics, search for the `WITH_BULLET` macro.

---

Setting the properties and executing the rigid body simulation are separate operations.

Adding a rigid body simulation to an object in the UI results in call to `ED_rigidbody_object_add` (`rigidbody_object.c`) which in turn calls `BKE_rigidbody_add_object` (`rigidbody.c`). This functions creates the rigid body world by calling `rigidbody_add_object_to_scene()` (`rigidbody.c`) in case it doesn't exist and allocates the memory for `RigidBodyOb` through `BKE_rigidbody_create_object()` (`rigidbody.c`) and assigns default values.

For instance the *mass* property is displayed in the `PHYSICS_PT_rigid_body_settings` panel (`properties_physics_rigidbody.py`). It references the RNA property defined in `rna_rigidbody.c` which calls `rna_RigidBodyOb_mass_set()` when a new value is assigned through the UI. This stores the value in `RigidBodyOb` of the object and updates the state of the Bullet Physics through `RB_body_set_mass()` (`rb_bullet_api.cpp`).

Adding a rigid body constraint results in a call to `ED_rigidbody_constraint_add()` (`rigidbody_constraint.c`). A constraint collection is created if it doesn't already exist. The constraint is created through `BKE_rigidbody_create_constraint` (`rigidbody.c`) and added to the constraint collection through `BKE_collection_object_add()` (`rigidbody.c`).

When starting the simulation it executes the function `BKE_rigidbody_eval_simulation` (`deg_builder_nodes.cc`) which calls `BKE_rigidbody_do_simulation` (`rigidbody.c`). It uses the properties for the world, objects and constraints that were previously assigned.

---

The explanation of the call stack is a simplification of all the operations that happen during configuration and simulation. They are meant as an overview for where certain steps can be found in the code and not a complete explanation of the performed operations.

Comment: Thank you very much ;-)