# Documentation on the mathematical models used by Blender physics engines

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation, mathematics

I need to know which mathematical models Blender uses during rigid body simulation and fluid simulation (*e.g.* Lattice Boltzmann).

Is there something like that in the Blender manual or do I need to search in other "technical" manuals?

Comment: For some areas of Blender there are additional information in the [Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source), e.g. for Cycles. However for rigid body simulations and fluid simulations you will have to look at the source code. For the rigid body simulation [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156690/blender-physics-constraint-implementation-sources) should point you to the relevant files and for the fluid simulation (2.82 and beyond) you would need to look at mantaflow and its integration in Blender.

Answer (score 4):

#### Rigid bodies

There is no mention of the underlying physics engine in [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/physics/rigid_body/introduction.html) for the current version v2.81.

However, up until version 2.79, Blender used to have also a Game Engine, which shared the same physics with the general Rigid Body World used for animation. Its [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/game_engine/physics/introduction.html) gave more away in terms of the underlying engine:

> *Blender includes advanced physics simulation in the form of the Bullet Physics Engine ([Bullet Physics](https://pybullet.org/wordpress/)). Most of your work will involve setting the right properties on the objects in your scene, then you can sit back and let the engine take over.*

As far as I can tell, Blender still uses Bullet. Unfortunately, the [Bullet documentation](https://pybullet.org/wordpress/index.php/forum-2/) doesn't explain things from the first principles up: it rather explains the settings, API and examples.

#### Liquids

The current (up to Blender 2.81) fluid engine is based on Lattice Boltzmann (LBM) through the `elbeem` library.

However, it is being replaced (version 2.82) by a new fluid engine, Mantaflow.

Comment: Rigid bodies do indeed still use Bullet.